# I have a contact form that is sending blank emails?

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I am a complete novice before we start!

I have had a contact form created for me using PHP. I have embedded the code into my emailer html and changed the email address in the php file.

The people who created it say it works fine on their server and have sent me the emails to prove it does.

After clicking Submit, the email comes through but it is blank, any ideas?

**PHP Code (file name `simple-mailprocess_v2`):**

```
<?
    $to= ('info@cre8ivo.co.uk'); 
    $subjectline= ('Website - form enquiry - Speak to a private medical insurance     specialist'); 
    $thanks=('thankyou.html');
    $return=('Location:'.$thanks);
    if (sizeof($_POST)) {
        $body = "";
        while(list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
            $body .= "$key: \n $val \n\n";
            // Check if all fields have been filled in
            if(empty($val)) {
                echo ("<b><li>either one or more required fields have not been completed. Go <a     href='javascript: history.go(-1)'>Back</a> and try again</li></b>");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
    // Secure the headers
    $security = "From: \r\n";
    $security .= "Reply-To: \r\n";
    $security .= "Return-Path: \r\n";
    $security .= "CC: \r\n";
    $security .= "BCC: \r\n";
    // Send the email.
    if ( mail($to,$subjectline,$body,$security) ) {
        header($return);
    } else {
        echo "The email has failed!";
   }
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Any more info need then I will provide, not sure what it needed sorry!

Many Thanks,
Jane.

Comment: did you do a `var_dump()` of each of your fields to see if they contain a string? `var_dump($to, $subjectline, $yourothervariables);`

Comment: I think the `$body .= "$key: \n $val \n\n";` didn't set any value

Comment: Hi Alex, I have not written this code (someone has written it for me) and I wouldn't know where to start editing it!  Where do I put this code to test? Thanks Jane

Comment: Sherin thanks, why would it work on their server (the person who created it) and not mine? Jane

Comment: You can do the `var_dump();` in any spot on that php file. Frankly, some of the code does look funny, like unnecessary parenthesis on the first few lines. Just do some `var_dump()`ing in that same file, and you'll see what's blank/null when it shouldn't be - that will show you were to start hunting for errors

Comment: That line Sherin pointed out might make more sense  `$body .= $key.":\n".$val."\n\n";`

Comment: I have got it working and tested it on my server. My next problem is that I am embedding the form as part of a html email that I am send ing through a mailer program such as Mailchimp. However the email is coming in blank again when filled in from my email? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing $HTTP_POST_VARS to $_POST..

$HTTP_POST_VARS [deprecated] -> [from php](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: @Alex Demchak Thanks, I have got it working and tested it on my server.  My next problem is that I am embedding the form as part of a html email that I am send ing through a mailer program such as Mailchimp.  However the email is coming in blank again when filled in from my email?  Any ideas?